# How to optimize redundant code in c#?

Tags: c#, generics, optimization, methods

I have the following class. EDITED: (And I know it's not a good practice):

```
public class BussinesRuleA
{
    private string _connectionString;

    public BussinesRuleA(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public List<persitenceRuleA> getDATA_A(persitenceRuleA perRA, int acao)
    {
        //EDITED: IT´S MANDATORY make A NEW instance to this DATA ACCESS class
        //        The connectionString was removed from the constructor 
        dalRuleA dalRA = new dalRuleA(); 
        List<persitenceRuleA> lst = new List<persitenceRuleA>();
        try
        {
            lst = dalRA.getDATA(perRA, acao);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            dalRA = null;
        }
        return lst;
    }
}
```

I Want to do the same thing in Generic way. How can I recreate the code to the method above?
I try to do the code below but it´s not working. **EDITED:** The name of the method was changed

```
    public List<TPer> getDATA_Generic<TPer, TDal>(TPer per, int acao) 
           where TDal: new()
    {
        TDal _dal = new TDal(); 
        List<TPer> _lst = new List<TPer>();
        try
        {
            _lst = _dal.getDATA(TPer,acao); //**EDITED**: The call for getDATA method was changed 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            _dal = default(TDal);
        }
        return _lst;
    }
```

**EDITED**: The code above works, but I dont want to do:

```
    public List<TPer> getDATA<TPer, TDal>(TPer per, int acao)
```

**EDITED**: Instead, I want something like this :

```
    public List<TPer> getDATA<TPer>(TPer per, int acao)
```

**EDITED**: And create a new instance of TDal inside the method, i dont know if it's possible, or if exists a workaround to solve this issue:

```
    TDal _dal = new TDal();
```

Actually I have several class, something like that:

```
    BussinesRuleA: method getDATA, call to persitenceRuleA , dalRuleA
    BussinesRuleB: method getDATA, call to persitenceRuleB , dalRuleB
    BussinesRuleC: method getDATA, call to persitenceRuleC , dalRuleC
```

I want to reduce the rewrite of code,  avoiding have to write a lot of methods, I want to use TPer and TDal with generics to make this:

```
    BussinesRuleA: method getDATA<T>, call to TPer , TDal
    BussinesRuleB: method getDATA<T>, call to TPer , TDal
    BussinesRuleC: method getDATA<T>, call to TPer , TDal
```

Comment: What's not working with your refactored code?

Comment: Is there anything in common with the `persitenceRule`'s? Do they inherit from the same base class?

Comment: You should try to post this to the codereview subsite of stackexchange.

Comment: @nandox - Use @ + the username. It'll alert them when you're responding to them.

Comment: Thank you @gunr2171. Not, they dont inherit from a base class. And the generic code works, but I don't know how to create a instance of TDal without put TDal on the declaration of the method.

Comment: @gunr2171, I posted a simplified version of this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759951/is-it-possible-create-a-new-instance-of-a-generic-type-inside-the-body-of-a-gene
I appreciate if you culd take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to put generic constraint about specific constructor availabilty, so you cannot guarantee inside the method that `TDal _dal = new TDal(_connectionString);` is possible.

I would refactor it then to provide dal externally:

```
public List<TRule> getData<TRule>(TRule perRA, IDal<TRule> dalRA, int acao)
{
    List<TRule> list = new List<TRule>();
    try
    {
        list = dalRA.getDATA(perRA, acao);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        dalRA = null;
    }
    return list;
}
```

assuming:

```
internal interface IDal<TRule>
{
    List<TRule> getDATA(TRule perRA, int acao);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Konrad Kokosa, and @gunr2171:
Assuming that I changed my code to: 
    TDal _dal = new TDal();
Without no parameters in the constructor, is it possible to  optimize the original method? In fact, I need to do maintenance an existing code with several classes that follow the same redundant structure.

Comment: I posted a simplified version of this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759951/is-it-possible-create-a-new-instance-of-a-generic-type-inside-the-body-of-a-gene
I appreciate if you culd take a look.