# Is it possible create a new instance of a generic type inside the body of a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, optimization, parameters, instance

Assuming the following method, and I know it does not work:

I want to create a new instance of a generic type

```
public List<TPer> getDATA<TPer>(TPer per, int acao) where TDal: new()
{
    //Is it possible create a new instance of a generic type inside the body of a generic method?
    TDal dal = new TDal(); //<-- I know it is NOT OK 
    List<TPer> lst = new List<TPer>();

    lst = dal.getDATA(per, acao);
    return lst;
}
```

I could write something like this:

```
List<TPer> getDATA<TPer,TDal>(TPer per, int acao) where TDal: new()
```

But, the program that will call this method dont have access to `TDal`:

Is it possible to call this method using an empty parameter? or create a new instance of a generic type inside the body of a generic method?

`<TDal>` would be generic too, but I don't know if it's possible create it, as a new generic type, inside of this generic method in C#.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to achieve - or why you're creating a new `List<TPer>` and then immediately discarding it. In what way is `TDal dal = new TDal()` "NOT OK"?

Comment: The first version of the method doesn't show what `TDal` is supposed to be and where it's coming from. What about it?

Comment: It would be better if you edited your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24739303/1043380), instead of reposting.

Comment: @JonSkeet, It is not OK  because of compiler error: "The type or namespace name 'TDal' could not be found". And lst is the return of the method.

Comment: @Jon, thank you for your comment, I want to make a new instance of TDal, and TDal would be generic too, but I don't know if it's possible create it inside of this generic method in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your generic type implement an interface.  Then place restrictions in your generic method to only accept types that implement that interface.  This will allow you to call methods on your newly constructed item as it's known to have those methods.

```
public interface ITest
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public void GetData<T, U>(T varA, int acao) where U: ITest, new()
{
    var item = new U();
    item.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I liked this answer. Well, my knowledge in C# and generics it´s not much advanced, and my real project it's much more complex than the code in this question, but I will try to implement your suggestion.

Comment: If this solution is implementable, please mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted, but it helped me to understand better about generics. Would like to wait a little more, if possible for more answers. Maybe if I mark as a correct answer, people will not give anymore answers.

Answer (score 0):

How can generic getDATA know what is TDal?
It must be declared in the method getDATA or in the class containing the method i.e.

```
class MyGenericClass<TDal> where TDal:new()
{
    public List<TPer> getDATA<TPer>(TPer per, int acao) where TDal : new()
    {
        TDal dal = new TDal();
        List<TPer> lst = new List<TPer>();

        lst = dal.getDATA(per, acao);
        return lst;
    }
}
```

In both cases the caller needs to know the TDal.

If you need to avoid this you can make something in getDATA that from per.GetType() retrieves the TDal type and then instantiate that class.
I.e.

```
    public List<TPer> getDATA<TPer>(TPer per, int acao)
    {

        List<TPer> lst = new List<TPer>();

        IDal dal;

        switch (per.GetType().Name)
        {
            case "Person": 
                dal = new DalPerson();
                break;
            case "Car":
                dal = new DalCar();
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("I dont like per");
        }

        lst = dal.getDATA(per, acao);
        return lst;
    }
```